# Connecting FETs to make a push pull GPIO

Tags: fet, push-pull

We have a circuit that generates pulses via GPIO. We use FETs for the `push-pull` mechanism.

Our schematic:

[image: current push-pull mechanism]

[Description of the `push-pull` mechanism.](https://open4tech.com/open-drain-output-vs-push-pull-output/)

[image: push-pull diagarm]

According to [this source,](https://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/MOSFET/MOSFET.html) connecting two FETS like that is a bad practice which can cause short-circuit.

[image: is it a bad partice?]

Should we change our design? Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: You can work this out yourself. Imagine the gates were held at a DC level of 1.65 volts, what current would flow through both MOSFETs. Inspecting the data sheets should give you an indication. So should using a circuit simulator (a very useful tool).

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not familiar with the MOSFETs in this schematic, but most of the ones I commonly use have a Vgs threshold above 1.65v, so the current would generally be reasonably low.

Comment: @occipita correct.

Comment: @occipita, CSD17484F4 30-V  Vgs(thershold) is 0.85

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the case of bipolar transistors in that role:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdARlX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The base-emitter junctions of these transistors are just diodes. Look carefully, for a couple of problems:

- The direction of the diodes clearly show a route for current from the positive supply right down to ground. That's almost a short circuit, and current will be huge. Junctions will die.
- Both junctions have well over 0.7V across them. Both transistors are switched very, very on, if they haven't died already from excessive base current. That's another path for unlimited current to flow between the supply rails. One or both of those transistors will soon be toast.
- Whatever is connected to those bases will also have to supply a lot of  current, and may also fall victim to this design.

In the case of MOSFETS, the base current issue goes away, because there's extremely high impedance between the MOSFET's gate and its channel. Let's have a look at the situation where the power supply voltage is very small, 3.3V, and the gate threshold voltage for each MOSFET is 2.0V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRwOu7.png)</sup>

Both of those transistors are off right now, because neither has sufficient \$V_{GS}\$ to switch them on. The top transistor can only switch on when the potential at its gate falls below 1.3V (3.3V - 1.3V = 2.0V). The lower transistor requires a gate potential of +2.0V to switch on. Clearly the situation where both transistors are on simultaneously (creating a short circuit across the supply, and causing current to "shoot-through") is not possible here.

Look at what happens when we increase the power supply to +12V, using the same components, and placing their gates half way between supply potentials:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0UKv4.png)</sup>

Now both transistors are switched fully on, even though all we did was increase the supply voltage, keeping the gates at a half way potential. That's obviously going to cause some smoke somewhere.

When we connected BJT bases together, we formed a near short-circuit across the power supply, but that problem is gone here because the gates are electrically insulated from the channels. That's not to say that gate current won't be an issue *at all*; even though the gates are isolated, they have capacitance with the channel, and that capacitance is a very low impedance at high frequencies. When gate potentials are switched between high and low very fast and frequently, a very significant amount of current can flow into and out of them.

Still, nothing bad will happen if the both gates are at +12V, or both are at 0V. It's during the transition between those states that the problem of shoot-through occurs.

Aside from shoot-though, this design is a good one, and is in common use. There are a number of approaches designers can take regarding shoot-through:

- Make sure gate transition is as fast as possible, spending as little time as possible in that zone where both transistors are on.
- Use transistors with gate thresholds closer to (or greater than) half-supply.
- Include deliberate resistance in the channels, to limit current.
- Change how we drive the gates, to introduce "dead-time" that ensures that one transistor is switched off before the other is switched on.
- Suck it up, accept that shoot-through occurs, that's the price you pay for speed.
- The other thing that someone is bound to bring up in the comments.

Comment: Hey, great answer! Appreciate it alot

Comment: Quick question:” even though the gates are isolated, they have capacitance with the channel, and that capacitance is a very low impedance at high frequencies. When gate potentials are switched between high and low very fast and frequently” what is considered to be fast? 100hz? 1khz? 1mhz?

Comment: @oak I wish there was a quick answer. It's a capacitance, so the current in and out of the gate is proportional to the *rate of change* of gate voltage. It's often overlooked that because it's a capacitance between gate and channel, it's also proportional to the rate of change of voltage at the source or drain, which can be much more of a problem...

Comment: @oak So it's not just frequency, it's rise rate and fall rate. The rate determines peak current, the frequency determines average current. You must consider both. If you are switching at 10Hz, and get get away with rise and fall times of many microseconds, perhaps peak gate current can be milliamps, and average current almost nothing....

Comment: @oak but if you are switching the gate potential up and down at many kiolhertz, with transition times in the nanoseconds, peak current can easily be tens of amps, with averages approaching amps. That's such a hand-wavy answer, though, because there are so many variables, not the least of which is model of MOSFET.

Comment: @oak Actually, I should be more precise - gate current due to gate-channel capacitance is closely related to the rate of change of *potential difference* between gate and channel. I was taught at university about this, but it wasn't until many years later when SPICE-like simulators became available to proles like me, that I was finally able to properly grasp it all. I really recommend you use simulators to see what's going on without having to blow up real MOSFETs. Seriously, check out CircuitLab and build a push-pull setup.

Comment: one comment on the above:  the Vgs are 0.85, and -0.95, and we have "in" as 3.3v. so in this case we have the "short times" for the transition from 0 to 3.3v, right?

Comment: @oak I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I meant that your analyze on the above, with 3.3v will show that for the selected fets I do have issue there ,right? because of the small "shorts" time when the voltage is raising from zero to 3. I.e at the very short moment that the input voltage is 2v, there is a shorcuts between ground and power

Comment: @oak, Ah I see. Yes the two devices in your own circuit will switch on simultaneously as their gates traverse the middle section. You will probably have to deal with that using dead-time or by limiting current some other way. What are you driving? What's connected to the drains?

Comment: one side we have SN74LVC2G17DSFR which power with 3.3v as well, the otherside trigger image acquisition i.e trigger cameras + flashlight

Comment: @oak what amount of current is required by everything connected to HTRIG1?

Comment: About 60 milliamperes

Comment: we have XC8110AA01MR-G as current limit, 850 miliamps. Do you think its good enough for solving the **short** "simultaneously" switch on?

Comment: @oak With \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ of 1V or so you will definitely have shoot-through, and with \$R_{DS(ON)}=0.2\Omega\$ it will be many amps, which will cause your supply to drop out momentarily, if capped to 850mA.

Comment: thanks, when the cap of 850am, do you think it worth changing the design? or the shoot-through  wont be a real issue because of the current limitation?

Comment: as far as my understandthing the "shoot-through" will only happen when voltage change from 0 to 3.3v and vise versa, so it only happen for very short time ("pico seconds maybe?)

Comment: @oak gate capacitance will make it impossible to achieve picosecond transitions, maybe tens of nanoseconds if you drive the gate properly. Gate driving is a whole other issue. But yes, the current spike will be as short as the time it takes to make the gate transition. It will only be a couple of amps (given the \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ for those devices) which isn't much, really. You should post another question, with a bit more info about source "1Y "in your schematic, and ask for help to mitigate shoot-through.

Comment: @oak Also, are you sure you need a push-pull? Is your load going to sink *and* source current?

Comment: well we are actually triggering optocouplers today, so probably not need a pull. but thinking on the future it may be good idea to have the abilities to do it one day?

Comment: how bad is 10 nanoseconds of 3.3/R_DS(ON)? which has a limit of 850 miliapms by XC8110AA01MR-G

Comment: For those CSDxxx MOSFETs, \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ is 0.13Ω and 0.17Ω, so if current were unlimited that would be \$\frac{3.3}{0.13+0.17}=11A\$. However, it *is* limited, so the 3.3V rail would drop to \$0.85A \times (0.13Ω+0.17Ω)=0.26V\$ for a few nanoseconds. You tell me if that's acceptable or not!

Comment: Your gates have a combined capacitance of 150pF + 120pF = 270pF. A standard CMOS output of 10mA would take 100ns to charge that capacitance to 3.3V.  Maybe for 50ns of that time the transistors would be simultaneously on, passing 0.85A, and dropping out the power supply to 0.26V.